# I want to add Pictures to Categories and Product dynimaclly but I face broken Images

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nopcommerce

I made a small console application using c# 
that get all categories and loop into them if finds picture Id =0 as I inserted before in Database 
call this function

```
 protected virtual byte[] LoadPictureFromFile(string filePath)
        {          
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                return new byte[0];
            return File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        }
```

which filepath is "C:\nopCommerce_3.70_Source\Presentation\Nop.Web\Content\Images\Thumbs\images"

and Then Insert it in Picture table in Database 
after that update category table row with the new Picture Id

till now there is no problem

but the probelm appears when I run the nopCommerce Solution on chrome explorer and try to show the image category

```
1- it copy the inserted images in "C:\nopCommerce_3.70_Source\Presentation\Nop.Web\Content\Images\Thumbs" folder with concatenation of 0000103_450_mypic

2- appears it broken in browser and the folder "C:\nopCommerce_3.70_Source\Presentation\Nop.Web\Content\Images\Thumbs"
```

please help

Comment: I am sorry. Having hard time to understand your question. Are you trying to bulk insert images for categories if a given category's picture id = 0? And you are using a console app to automate it?

Comment: @Jeyara Yes! exactly what I try to Do.

Comment: check the answer below in answer section

Answer (score 0):

OK..my best guess is that you forgot to set IsNew Flag to true in Picture table. If it is not set, NopCommerce wont re-generate that image and you will end up with broken image.